# ExponentialSmoothing - What prediction method to use for this date plot?

Tags: python, data-science, prediction

I currently have these data points of date vs cumulative sum. I want to predict the cumulative sum for future dates using python. What prediction method should I use?

[image: Plot of date vs cumulative sum]

My dates series are in this format: `['2020-01-20', '2020-01-24', '2020-01-26', '2020-01-27', '2020-01-30', '2020-01-31'] dtype='datetime64[ns]'`

- I tried spline but seems like spline can't handle date-time series
- I tried Exponential Smoothing for time series forecasting but the result is incorrect. I don't 
  understand what predict(3) means and why it returns the predicted sum for dates I already have. I copied this code from an example. Here's my code for exp smoothing:

  ```
  fit1 = ExponentialSmoothing(date_cumsum_df).fit(smoothing_level=0.3,optimized=False)

  fcast1 = fit1.predict(3)

  fcast1



  2020-01-27       1.810000
  2020-01-30       2.467000
  2020-01-31       3.826900
  2020-02-01       5.978830
  2020-02-02       7.785181
  2020-02-04       9.949627
  2020-02-05      11.764739
  2020-02-06      14.535317
  2020-02-09      17.374722
  2020-02-10      20.262305
  2020-02-16      22.583614
  2020-02-18      24.808530
  2020-02-19      29.065971
  2020-02-20      39.846180
  2020-02-21      58.792326
  2020-02-22     102.054628
  2020-02-23     201.038240
  2020-02-24     321.026768
  2020-02-25     474.318737
  2020-02-26     624.523116
  2020-02-27     815.166181
  2020-02-28    1100.116327
  2020-02-29    1470.881429
  2020-03-01    1974.317000
  2020-03-02    2645.321900
  2020-03-03    3295.025330
  2020-03-04    3904.617731
  ```

What method will be best suited for the sum values prediction that seems to be exponentially increasing?
Also I'm pretty new to data science with python so go easy on me. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Exponential Smoothing only works for data without any missing time series values. I'll show you forecasting of your data +5 days into future for your three methods mentioned:

- Exponential Fit (your guess "seems to be exponentially increasing")
- Spline interpolation
- Exponential Smoothing

Note: I got your data by data-thiefing it from your plot and saved the dates to `dates` and the data values to `values`

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from statsmodels.tsa.holtwinters import ExponentialSmoothing
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
from scipy.interpolate import splrep, splev

df = pd.DataFrame()
# mdates.date2num allows functions like curve_fit and spline to digest time series data
df['dates'] = mdates.date2num(dates)
df['values'] = values 

# Exponential fit function
def exponential_func(x, a, b, c, d):
    return a*np.exp(b*(x-c))+d

# Spline interpolation
def spline_interp(x, y, x_new):
    tck = splrep(x, y)
    return splev(x_new, tck)

# define forecast timerange (forecasting 5 days into future)
dates_forecast = np.linspace(df['dates'].min(), df['dates'].max() + 5, 100)
dd = mdates.num2date(dates_forecast)

# Doing exponential fit
popt, pcov = curve_fit(exponential_func, df['dates'], df['values'], 
                       p0=(1, 1e-2, df['dates'][0], 1))

# Doing spline interpolation
yy = spline_interp(df['dates'], df['values'], dates_forecast)
```

So far straight forward (except of the `mdates.date2num` function). Since you got missing data you have to use spline interpolation on your actual data to fill missing time spots with interpolated data

```
# Interpolating data for exponential smoothing (no missing data in time series allowed)
df_interp = pd.DataFrame()
df_interp['dates'] = np.arange(dates[0], dates[-1] + 1, dtype='datetime64[D]')
df_interp['values'] = spline_interp(df['dates'], df['values'], 
                                    mdates.date2num(df_interp['dates']))
series_interp = pd.Series(df_interp['values'].values, 
                          pd.date_range(start='2020-01-19', end='2020-03-04', freq='D'))

# Now the exponential smoothing works fine, provide the `trend` argument given your data 
# has a clear (kind of exponential) trend
fit1 = ExponentialSmoothing(series_interp, trend='mul').fit(optimized=True)
```

You can plot the three methods and see how their prediction for the upcoming five days is

```
# Plot data
plt.plot(mdates.num2date(df['dates']), df['values'], 'o')
# Plot exponential function fit
plt.plot(dd, exponential_func(dates_forecast, *popt))
# Plot interpolated values
plt.plot(dd, yy)
# Plot Exponential smoothing prediction using function `forecast`
plt.plot(np.concatenate([series_interp.index.values, fit1.forecast(5).index.values]),
     np.concatenate([series_interp.values, fit1.forecast(5).values]))
```

Comparison of all three methods shows that you have been right choosing exponential smoothing. It looks way better in forecasting the future five days than the other two methods

[image]

---

Regarding your other question

> I don't understand what predict(3) means and why it returns the predicted sum for dates I already have.

`ExponentialSmoothing.fit()` returns a [`statsmodels.tsa.holtwinters.HoltWintersResults`](https://www.statsmodels.org/stable/generated/statsmodels.tsa.holtwinters.HoltWintersResults.html#statsmodels.tsa.holtwinters.HoltWintersResults) Object which has two function you can use fore prediction/forecasting of values: [`predict`](https://www.statsmodels.org/stable/generated/statsmodels.tsa.holtwinters.HoltWintersResults.predict.html#statsmodels.tsa.holtwinters.HoltWintersResults.predict) and [`forecast`](https://www.statsmodels.org/stable/generated/statsmodels.tsa.holtwinters.HoltWintersResults.forecast.html#statsmodels.tsa.holtwinters.HoltWintersResults.forecast):

`predict` takes a `start` and `end` observation of your data and applies the ExponentialSmoothing model to the corresponding date values. For predicting values into the future you have to specify an `end` parameter which is in the future

```
>> fit1.predict(start=np.datetime('2020-03-01'), end=np.datetime64('2020-03-09'))
2020-03-01    4240.649526
2020-03-02    5631.207307
2020-03-03    5508.614325
2020-03-04    5898.717779
2020-03-05    6249.810230
2020-03-06    6767.659081
2020-03-07    7328.416024
2020-03-08    7935.636353
2020-03-09    8593.169945
Freq: D, dtype: float64
```

In your example `predict(3)` (which equals `predict(start=3)` predicts the values based on your dates starting with the third date and without any forecasting.

`forecast()` does only forecasting. You pass simply the number of observation you want to forecast into the future.

```
>> fit1.forecast(5)
2020-03-05    6249.810230
2020-03-06    6767.659081
2020-03-07    7328.416024
2020-03-08    7935.636353
2020-03-09    8593.169945
Freq: D, dtype: float64
```

Since both functions are based on the same `ExponentialSmoothing.fit` model, their values are equal for equal dates.

Comment: Thank you so much! I'm going to try exponential smoothing now. Can you please tell me what "3" is in fit1.predict(3)? If you want to predict for the next 5 days do you just pass 5 into predict()? Thanks!

Comment: @ShafinM You're welcome. Sorry I forgot to paste also the code plotting the data/models which might answers your question already. However, I edited the answer and added a brief explanation of how to use `fit.predict()` and `fit.forecast()`.